# Can't see google ads more than 9

Tags: adsense, google-ad-manager

[**Here is the demo link**](http://teenvoice.co/test/)

How you see, only 8 ads are visible in page but I have 14 ads. I have read about ad limitations [**here**](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ad_limit_per_page) but can't understand is it my situation or not ? Can someone give me exact answer why I can't see more than 8 ads ? Can it be some premium account for seeing more ads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link stated on the page you refer:

```
Ad limit per page

Currently, on each page AdSense publishers may place:

    Up to three AdSense for content units
    Up to three link units
    Up to two search boxes
```

You are trying to put more than three content units on one page.

Comment: So I can have only 3 ads in a page and no more ? @Davey D

Comment: Yes, you can only combine it with three link units and two search boxes. But you won't make more money just by putting up more ads on a page. You will scare people away. So, place them wisely.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me much. @Davey D